# Why does Margaret Thatcher's narration come in the middle while Dennis is speaking to her?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-iron-lady

In the scene from ***The Iron Lady* (2011)** where Denis is speaking to Margaret Thatcher, suddenly Denis' voice was muted and Margaret's narration comes in and says these lines:

> When the Himalayan peasant meets the he-bear in his pride...

and Denis' voice resumes.

[image: Scene from The Iron Lady]

I don't understand why suddenly Margaret Thatcher's narration comes in this scene.

Answer (score 2):

### She appears to be trying to distract herself from the vision of her dead husband as well as attempting to recall June's name.

I haven't seen the film, but from [the script](https://stephenfollows.com/resource-docs/scripts/Iron-Lady-screenplay.pdf) it sounds like she's trying to ignore the vision of her husband and attempt to recall June's name.

She can't remember the name initially, but *is* able to recall a complex Rudyard Kipling quote until she eventually remembers the name.

> **INT. DRAWING ROOM. CHESTER SQUARE. PRESENT.** DUSK.
>
> MARGARET sits reading DENIS’ spy novel.
>
> DENIS: She does it in the end. Kills him
>
> MARGARET slams the book closed.
>
> DENIS (CONT’D): I don’t know why you’re being so scratchy.
>
> MARGARET’s eyes dart to the clock.
>
> DENIS (CONT’D): It’s not as if you’ve got anyone else to talk to.
>
> **Shaking her head, MARGARET tries to block him out.**
>
> **MARGARET (V.O.)**: **When the Himalayan peasant meets the he-bear in his pride -**
>
> **DENIS: You know, it’s a marvel to me that you can still quote huge chunks of
>   Kipling but try remembering the name of that woman who’s just made you
>   that godawful cold collation... No? Come on... you can do it... month
>   of the year... one syllable... rhymes with moon ...**
>
> MARGARET: (sudden/like a lightbulb): June.
>
> MARGARET turns to DENIS, a quiet appalling victory.
>
> DENIS: June! Bingo. Knew you’d get there in the end. “When the Himalayan
>   peasant meets the he-bear in his pride, He shouts to scare the
>   monster, who will often turn aside, but the she-bear thus accosted
>   rends the peasant tooth and nail. For the female of the species is
>   more deadly than the male...”
>
> As he continues, MARGARET reaches for the remote, turns the television
>   on. She moves onto the radio. Then the stereo. She moves on, talking
>   to herself -

In her final years, Thatcher developed dementia. Many people with Dementia are unable to retain short-term memories but can recall details from many years before.

The scene seems to be a way to show how her mind and memory were working at that time of her life.